# Find error in jobsteps of all jobs that ran over night

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, job-scheduling

Every night, there are many jobs (SSIS packages and stored procedures) that run. Is there a T-SQL query to get all jobsteps that failed in the past 24 hours?

Thanks in advance, Kind Regards.

Comment: @an33sh Thanks, it is useful info. However, I am looking for failed jobs specifically.

Comment: There is a `run_status` column which could give you the result

Comment: Thanks, problem solved!!